# Jacobian Matrix of 6DOF Body (with IMU)

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, control-theory, quaternions, nonlinear-system

I am trying to derive the analytical Jacobian for a system that is essentially the equations of motion of a body (6 degrees of freedom) with gyro and accelerometer measurements.
This is part of an Extended Kalman Filter.

The system state is given by:
$
\mathbf{x} = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{q}\\
\mathbf{b_\omega}\\
\mathbf{v}\\
\mathbf{b_a}\\
\mathbf{p}\\
\end{array}
\right)
$

where $q$ is the quaternion orientation of the body expressed in the global frame, $b_\omega$ and $b_a$ are the biases in the gyro and accelerometer respectively (expressed in the body frame) and $v$ and $p$ are the velocity and position of the body expressed in the global frame. All vectors are [3x1] except $q$ which is [4x1] in $[w,x,y,z]^\top$ format, and $R$ (below) which is [3x3].

The equations of motion $\frac{dx}{dt}=\dot{x}$ (t is time) are:
$$
\dot{\mathbf{q}} = \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{q} \otimes 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
\hat{\omega}\\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\dot{\mathbf{b_\omega}} = 0 \\
\dot{\mathbf{v}} = R^\top (\hat{\mathbf{a}} + [\hat{\mathbf{\omega}}\times]R \mathbf{v})+ g \\
\dot{\mathbf{b_a}} = 0 \\
\dot{\mathbf{p}} = \mathbf{v}
$$
Second-order terms are ignored. $\hat{a} = a - b_a$ and $\hat{\omega} = \omega - b_\omega$ are the corrected accelerometer and gyro biases ($a$ and $\omega$ are known) and are expressed in the body frame. $R$ is the rotation matrix (DCM) formed from $q$ and $g$ is the gravity vector $[0,0,9.81]^\top$. These equations have been validated against an aerospace engineering software library.

I need the jacobian $F = \frac{d\dot{x}}{dx}$ but I cannot find this jacobian in any texts (I do find the error-state jacobian eg [this paper](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~stergios/papers/IROS07-IMUCam.pdf)).
I am struggling with doing this myself because I don't know how to handle the quaternion norm constraints. I also am concerned about the validity of a solution given through numerical differentiation.

Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated. This is going towards an open-source robot localisation project.

Comment: Its rather odd, if $q$ is in the state, why is that $\dot q$ is not? In this case, it is simply impossible to have a derivative of $\dot q$ w.r.t. $q$-they are independent in 2nd order dynamics! Remember that the state space is always a tangent bundle. And also $v$ is in inertial frame, but $\dot q$ is in body frame. Why?

Comment: @TroyWoo To put it simply, $\dot{q}$ is not in the state because it is not of direct interest. I'm sorry I don't know RE the tangent bundle. All the vectors in the state are in the inertial (global) frame except for the two bias terms $b_a$ and $b_\omega$; the body->inertial transformations are made where appropriate.

Comment: To put it simply, $d\dot q/dq=0$. Why does the rate of rotation has anything to do with rotation itself? On a second thought, if your definition of state can be different from a mathematical one simply because you want it that way, then this question should be an off-topic and should be addressed to robotics rather than here.

Comment: @TroyWoo (Note I corrected the $\dot{q}$ equation) The rate of change of the orientation is related to the orientation because of the equation given for $\dot{x}$, that comes from the (corrected) observation of the body-frame angular velocity $\hat{\omega}$. As far as I am aware the state I am giving is simply a reduced full-state. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You didn't get it...it doesn't matter if the expression for $\dot q$ contains $q$ or not...physically the derivative $d\dot q/dq$ (rigoroulsy speaking we should assign $q$ $\dot q$ 3-d coordinates) should always be zero.